# Error 18 The type or namespace name 'TeamFoundation' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls;
```

I added The reference from following paths  :

1)C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

I also tried :
2)C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

but it not work
what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it not exist than you need to include dll or nuget package which contains this name space.

You can find the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client namespace in \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0 on computers where Team Explorer is installed.

Read MSDN : [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.aspx)

[image]

Comment: using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls;  this dll does not exists.